# Why I can add a List as an argument in where it must be an iterable object?

Tags: list, dart, iterable

I have this code

```dart
var list = ['arg1=val1', 'arg2=val2', 'arg3=val3'];
var nlist = new List();
list.forEach( (e) {
  nlist.addAll(e.split('='));
});
print(nlist);
```

`addAll` needs an argument is `Iterable`. But in this case, `e.split()` return `List`, not `Iterable`.

So why i can do that?

Comment: You can use `nlist = list.expand((e) => e.split('='));` to simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` implements `Iterable` and therefore is an `Iterable` (see https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.List just below the title)

Comment: More specifically, Dart supports Polymorphism, and that is why you are able to pass an object of a subtype in place of the supertype. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29#Subtyping